# How to compare JsonBody responses in Postman

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I have one expected JSON Response Code and one, which I receive when I call an endpoint of an API. 
What I try to achieve is: 
that I can compare the JSON body together and see if they are matching. 
At the same time, I want to be able, to "remove" one attribute of the JSON with his value like "Name". 
So that everything can be compared expect the name key and his value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I completely understand your requirement but you can write your postman test as:

```
pm.test("response matches", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    delete jsonData.Name;
    let str = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
    pm.expect(str).to.include("stringified expected json data");
});
```

Refer: https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test_scripts/

Comment: Is it possible, just to get the "body" of the response via postman?

Comment: And how I can include the expected json, of my file into: 
pm.expect(str).to.include("stringified expected json data");

Comment: yes you can compare only body also using `pm.response.to.have.body("response_body_string");` its all given in the documentation.

Comment: you will have to paste the data of your file.